# Update membership status automatically

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, scheduled-job

Using CiviCRM 4.6.9 on Drupal.

We've never enabled automatic updating of membership status, but now it's time.

How to do this?  I remembered that there is a Scheduled Job for this, but in looking at the description it says that it's obsolete as of v 4.3.

It seems this functionality has migrated over to Scheduled Reminders, however we had not planned on doing membership reminders automatically.  Our membership director is very comfortable sticking with her own mass emailing of membership reminders on her own schedule.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I think the reminders portion of the memberships has migrated to "Scheduled Reminders" but I believe the status update portion remains in the "Scheduled Jobs" area.

Once you get to 4.7 that warning about reminders is gone:

[image: Membership status]

Comment: Thanks Laryn!  Not sure what conclusion to draw from this.  Are you saying that Scheduled Reminders uses the Scheduled Job, and I could still enabled the Scheduled Job and it will still work?

Comment: You can use the 'Member Status' job without using the 'Scheduled Reminders' functionality, which is now separate.