# Bug in the scheduled update of Membership Statuses?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-job

There seems to be a bug in the scheduled task 'Update Membership Statuses' in 4.4.3. 
We have just changed the rule for status 'Grace' to allow an extra month for the grace period. If I re-save a membership manually it changes the recently-expired membership back to a status of Grace. So far so good and it proves that the rules are in the correct order. 
But I would now expect the scheduled task to change the others that have recently Expired back to Grace. *It doesn't.* It reports "Finished execution of Update Membership Statuses with result: Success (Processed 878 membership records. Updated 0 records.)"

Scheduled status updates have worked in the past.

I've looked at '[membership statuses not being updated](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/membership-statuses-not-being-updated)' and '[Update membership status automatically](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/update-membership-status-automatically)' and even the very old '[Membership status not updating from pending](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=13921.0)' but these are all simpler cases.

Clearing the Civi caches didn't help.
Is the scheduled task logic different to the immediate logic?
CiviCRM is so damn fragile!
David

Comment: Thanks, JohnFF, but iIn this case all memberships are Individual and there are no relevant Relationships.

Answer (score 1):

A real fix is still needed but the following procedure appears to provide a reliable workaround:

- Set the Grace period to the new value;
- Disable the status 'Expired';
- Run the task 'Update Membership Statuses' so that memberships within the new Grace period are set to 'Grace'; (but don't just run Cron, as Cron only runs this particular update task once a day.)
- Re-enable the status 'Expired';
- Run the update task a second time to check that memberships that really should have expired do indeed correctly show as 'Expired'.

David

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally I know that there were a lot of bugs in 4.4 with regard to memberships not being transferred along relationships successfully. Have you looked at issues.civicrm.org?

**Recommended solution:** I would recommend updating to 4.4.18. You'll get so many bug fixes, and this may be one of them (I haven't checked). You'll also get important security fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled job calls the function `CRM_Member_BAO_Membership::updateAllMembershipStatus()` . This starts by getting all memberships that have types that are enabled, and don't have is_test set. For each:

- it then checks whether the contact is deceased (this seems to dominate over other rules)
- it skips inherited (non-primary) memberships
- it skips status overrides, and the specific statuses Pending, Cancelled and Expired
- it calculates the new status, and if that has changed, saves it.

(Edit: My first answer confused is_active with is_current_member. But it stands that it excludes expired memberships further down.)

Comment: So David, this means you should check if the contact is deceased, if its memberships are inherited from a group or a relationship, and if the membership is being overridden.

Comment: He's talking about setting Expired back to Grace- I think the scheduled job ignoring Expired is deliberate.

Comment: The scheduled task update should produce the same result as a manual re-save of the Membership, surely, except in the case where it cannot find a valid status and leaves the current status untouched. It should definitely recalculate if the current status is Expired; otherwise you can't use the rules to extend the Grace period.

Comment: Workaround: - disable status Expired; - run the update task; - enable status Expired; - run the update task. Result!

Comment: David - worth adding that as an answer.