# Members still have "new" status, after over a year and a half

Tags: drupal, civimember

Member rules dictate that members are "new" from start date to 3 months after start date. Nearly all the members in our database (4000+) are still marked as new. In fact, everyone is considered new unless they were cancelled by us by hand.

I have changed the rule so that members are only new for one month instead of three. What could be causing this issue? Cron is running. How do I fix and update user status?

The biggest problem with this is that we are a non-profit organization, and users aren't renewing their memberships because they are marked as status "new" even if their memberships expired a long time ago.

CiviCRM 4.7.15 Drupal 7.x

Comment: I realize now that this is a duplicate: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9206/update-membership-status-automatically and https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/membership-statuses-not-being-updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CiviCRM Scheduled Jobs, the job to check and update membership status was not enabled.